# Rails link database entry to local file dynamically

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, file

I am downloading files through the Rails app and I need to save the link to the local file (that was downloaded) in a database object..

So if I have

Media name:string url_link:string actual_file:string(??)

How do I define a path to a local file (so that I can also call/load it through rails sometime later)?

say the file is in applications folder (on same level with Gemfile etc..).

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Generally static assets like local files should be in your `public` directory in your rails app. Then your local path could be relative to your public directory, so the path `images/funny.jpg` would point to a file called `funny.jpg` in `your_project_folder/public/images/`.

However, attaching files to ActiveRecord objects is a wheel that has long since been invented. No sense in reinventing the wheel for your app. Look at [**paperclip**](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) as it provides everything you need to "attach" a file to your Rails model object, plus much much more.